# Getting wrong TimeStamp value when Retriving Data From Firebase ? (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My value event observer is retrieving wrong (value which does not exist in database) and then it triggers second time(which it should not) and gets me the Right values

here are the First Response:

```
      {
        fst = 1;
        img = 1;
        in = "-367569139";
        whoCame =     {
            id = "-L0nkjye-37lsfwR-c1x";
            mob = 9088858675;
            nm = Rajaram;
        };
    }
```

Here is the second response

```
{
       fst = 1;
        img = 1;
        in = "1515755886349";
        whoCame =     {
            id = "-L0nkjye-37lsfwR-c1x";
            mob = 9088858675;
            nm = Rajaram;
        };
    }
```

this only happens the very first time i start the App after that everything works fine. Here is the code:

```
histRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "whoCame/id").queryEqual(toValue: helper.key).observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in

   if let helperHistory = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                for each in helperHistory {

                    print("days", each.value)

                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Instead of using `.observe`try using `.observeSingleEvent `.

Comment: .observeSingleEvent is also getting the wrong values. atleast .value is firing again and getting the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

so i sent a support ticket to firebase, and they have told me that this is a known bug in firebase and as of 18 Jan 2018 their team is working on it.